# Why the transform is not moving to the new radius when changing the radius at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

if dc is not null i'm using a radius from another script and it's working fine when i'm changing the radius value in the DrawCircle script the transform in RotateAroundTarget is moving smooth to the new radius.

but if dc variable is null i want to use the local radius variable for setting the radius in runtime but when changing the radius the transform is not moving to the new radius.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateAroundTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float rotatingSpeed;
    public float movingSpeed;
    public Vector3 axis;
    public bool randomHeight;
    public float setRandomHeight = 1;
    public float radius;
    public DrawCircle dc;

    private float lastRadius;
    private bool move = false;
    private float t = 0.0f;
    public float upperLimit, lowerLimit, delay;
    private float prevHeight;
    private Vector3 radiusPosition;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (dc != null)
        {
            lastRadius = dc.xRadius;
        }
        else
        {
            lastRadius = radius;
        }
        move = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (dc != null)
        {
            radiusPosition = new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y, dc.xRadius);
        }
        else
        {
            radiusPosition = new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y, radius);
        }

        if (move == false)
        {
            transform.RotateAround(target.position, axis, rotatingSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            t += Time.deltaTime;

            if (t > delay)
            {
                prevHeight = setRandomHeight;
                setRandomHeight = Random.Range(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
                t = 0;
            }

            var tt = transform.position;
            tt.y = Mathf.Lerp(prevHeight, setRandomHeight, t);
            transform.position = tt;
        }

        if (dc != null)
        {
            if (lastRadius != dc.xRadius)
            {
                move = true;

                lastRadius = dc.xRadius;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (lastRadius != radius)
            {
                move = true;

                lastRadius = radius;
            }
        }

        if (move)
        {
            if (transform.position != radiusPosition)
            {
                float step = movingSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                    radiusPosition, step);
            }
            else
            {
                move = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. Btw, why not do a `float tempRadius; if (dc == null) tempRadius = radius; else tempRadius = dc.xRadius;` at the top of `Update`  then just use `tempRadius` instead of checking `dc`  and writing code twice every time you need to determine the radius. Much easier to maintain that way, less code duplication.

Comment: My guess would be that `dc` was not actually null when you tested.  As @Ruzihm pointed out, you can create a single radius variable at the top of update using something akin to `var tempRadius = dc?.xRadius ?? radius;`  Which first tries to access dc's xRadius, but if dc is null uses the local radius.  It will shorten your code a decent amount and make it easier to maintain.